# After rotating axis, ticks and legend overlaps and height doesn't work in c3js

Tags: legend, c3.js

For my business purpose, graph should be rotated. There is a property `axis.rotated` and I made it `true`. It beautifully rotated but now `y-axis` values and `legends` being overlapped.

[src in jsfiddle of my problem](https://jsfiddle.net/DreamRunner/x9r4zk0j/4/)

I tried `axis.y.height` to 100 or more greater but it doesn't work.

Code:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: '#my-chart',
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data1', 3000, 20000, 10000, 40000, 15000, 25000],
        ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
    ],
    type: 'bar'
},
axis: {
         rotated: true,
         x: {
              type: "categorized",
              categories:['abc','abcabc','abcabcabc','abcabcabc','abcabcabcabcabc','abcd'],
              tick: {
                        rotate: -60,
                        multiline: false
                  },
                  height:100
              },
         y: {
              tick: {
                   rotate : -60
               },
               height:50
           }
    }
});
```

But if I put `axis.y.tick.rotate:60`, It works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug that has a fix sitting in the pipeline -->
https://github.com/c3js/c3/pull/1766/

Until that gets added to the c3 master though, you can add the submitter's code as a standalone fix as below before you construct your charts (basically he wraps a couple of calculations in Math.abs):

```
c3.chart.internal.fn.getHorizontalAxisHeight = function (axisId) {
    var $$ = this, config = $$.config, h = 30;
    if (axisId === 'x' && !config.axis_x_show) { return 8; }
    if (axisId === 'x' && config.axis_x_height) { return config.axis_x_height; }
    if (axisId === 'y' && !config.axis_y_show) { 
        return config.legend_show && !$$.isLegendRight && !$$.isLegendInset ? 10 : 1; 
    }
    if (axisId === 'y2' && !config.axis_y2_show) { return $$.rotated_padding_top; }
    // Calculate x axis height when tick rotated
    if (axisId === 'x' && !config.axis_rotated && config.axis_x_tick_rotate) {
        h = 30 + $$.axis.getMaxTickWidth(axisId) * Math.cos(Math.PI * (90 - Math.abs(config.axis_x_tick_rotate)) / 180);
    }
    // Calculate y axis height when tick rotated
    if (axisId === 'y' && config.axis_rotated && config.axis_y_tick_rotate) {
        h = 30 + $$.axis.getMaxTickWidth(axisId) * Math.cos(Math.PI * (90 - Math.abs(config.axis_y_tick_rotate)) / 180);
    }
    return h + ($$.axis.getLabelPositionById(axisId).isInner ? 0 : 10) + (axisId === 'y2' ? -10 : 0);
};
```

See the new fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/x9r4zk0j/8/ for the fix in effect

If this helps you then give the guy who wrote the initial fix a thumbs up on github